# Is $\phi(n^k) = \phi(m^k)$ for any $n \neq m$ and $k > 2$?

Tags: number-theory

It's easy to find pairs of integers $n \neq m$ such that the Euler totient $\phi(n) = \phi(m)$, for example just take $n$ odd and $m = 2n$. However, some computer experiments that I have run indicate that for $k > 1$ it may be impossible to find such pairs for which $\phi(n^k) = \phi(m^k)$. Particularly it seems that no perfect squares yield the same totient. I don't see an obvious reason why this should be true. Could someone explain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no for the following reason. Let $p_1, \dots, p_k$ be the prime divisors of $n$ and $q_1, \dots, q_r$ be the prime divisors of $m$. Then if $\phi(n^k) = \phi(m^k)$, we have

$$n^{k-1} \cdot n \prod \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_i} \right) = m^{k-1} \cdot m \prod \left(1 - \frac{1}{q_i} \right).$$

Now cancel out the common $(1-1/p_i)$ factors on each side, i.e. the terms corresponding to common prime divisors of $n$ and $m$. Also, divide by $d^k=\gcd(n,m)^k$ where $n=ad$ and $m=bd$ to get

$$a^{k-1} \cdot a \prod \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_{i_k}} \right) = b^{k-1} \cdot b \prod 
\left(1 - \frac{1}{q_{k_i}} \right).$$

Now $p_{i_k}$ does not divide the gcd since it isn't a shared prime factor. Thus $p_{i_k}$ divides $a$. Similarly, $q_{k_i}$ divides $b$, and so we conclude that the RHS is $a^{k-1}$ times an integer and the LHS is $b^{k-1}$ times an integer.
Without loss of generality, we can have $b > a$. Now $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ which means the equation implies $b \; | \; a \prod \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_{i_k}} \right) < b$. This is a contradiction, so we cannot have $n \neq m$ such that $\phi(n^k) = \phi(m^k)$  for $k \geq 2$.

Comment: Could you perhaps further justify the statement "we might as well have $\gcd(n, m) = 1$"?

Comment: Yes. Let $d=\gcd(n,m)$ and $n=ad$ and $m=bd$. If $\phi(n^k) = \phi(m^k)$ then $$\phi(a^k) \phi(d^k) = \phi(b^k) \phi(d^k)$$ and we can cancel out the $\phi(d^k)$ terms.

Comment: We could only use the multiplicativity of $\phi$ if we also knew $\gcd(a, d) = 1$ and $\gcd(b, d) = 1$, which needn't be the case.

Comment: Good point! Let me think a bit.

Comment: How is the answer now @jaakhaamer?

Comment: It looks solid now, thanks! I'll have another look later but I'm happy to accept this.

Comment: One possible fix: The bit about "now $p_{i_k}$ does not divide the GCD" doesn't appear to make sense (at least not anymore).  However I think it is easily fixed by noting that $p_{i_k}$ divides $a^k$ (as the LHS is an integer) and therefore divides $a$.  Similarly on the right.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s another proof, I hope. It was harder to write up than I expected.

The following observation will be useful: If $k>1$ and $n$ is an integer, every prime factor of $n$ divides $\phi(n^k)$.

For the purpose of obtaining a contradiction, assume a counterexample to the result: $n\neq m$, $k>1$, and $\phi(n^k)=\phi(m^k)$.

Let $p$ be the largest prime divisor of $\phi(n^k)$ and let $n^k=p^{ik}b^k$ where $\gcd(p,b)=1$. Then $\phi(n^k)=\phi(p^{ik})\phi(b^k)$, and as previously noted, $\phi(b^k)$ is divisible by every prime factor of $b$. Then no prime greater than $p$ divides $b$ (or $n$), and $p$ divides $\phi(n^k)$ exactly $ik-1$ times. Because $\phi(n^k)=\phi(m^k)$, $p$ also divides $\phi(m^k)$ exactly $ik-1$ times, and $m$ can also have no prime factors greater than $p$, because none divides $\phi(m^k)$. Note that $p$ *is* a factor of $m$ and $n$, because $ik-1$ is nonnegative.

Thus $m^k=p^{ik}a^k$ where $\gcd(p,a)=1$ and all prime factors of $a$ are less than $p$. Note that $a=m/p^i$ and $b=n/p^i$.

But now $\displaystyle\phi(a^k)=\frac{\phi(m^k)}{\phi(p^{ik})}=\frac{\phi(n^k)}{\phi(p^{ik})}=\phi(b^k)$, and $a$ and $b$ provide a new counterexample and their largest prime factors are less than $p$.

By repeating this process, $m$ and $n$ can be taken to have no prime divisors, but this is a contradiction, because then each equals $1$, and $1\neq 1$.